# Do i need more gpio pins?

Tags: gpio, pi-zero-w, hat

Newbie here, I'm sorry if its a stupid question.

I have a project in which I need both touch input and LED output on my Raspberry Pi zero w.

The LED output (Neopixels) will need the 5V, the GPIO18 and one Ground pin. I got this working and everything is fine.

Additionally I would like to purchase [this](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2340), which seems to take all the GPIO pins, correct?

How can I go about this? Does the HAT really need all pins? Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to ask Adafruit about which GPIO are available when using that HAT.

https://pinout.xyz/ has details for some HATs.

Some HATs propagate the header pins on the HAT itself.  If yours does that will make it easier to get physical access to the GPIO.

Comment: Thanks. [Here](https://pinout.xyz/pinout/capacitive_touch_hat#) are the GPIO pins that the HAT uses. According to that it only takes two GPIO. But as you said, how to get access to the GPIO pins after the HAT is on there? HATs usually gets soldered on and therefore blocking access to all GPIO pins. Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: This HAT has headers included which must be soldered on. You could buy some [stacking headers](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2223) and solder them on instead, which will give you access to the pins from the top of the HAT.

Comment: @NomadMaker So stick the stacking headers on top of the pi, and basically put the HAT on these and the pins will stick out far enough to use something else on it as well?

Comment: Did you look at the headers on the link? You  use those headers for the HAT, and when soldered in with the female side down, the pins on top will be about the size of the normal Raspberry Pi pins. You could use these pins just like the normal Raspberry Pi pins.